# Is pointer conversion expensive or not?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Is pointer conversion considered expensive? (e.g. how many CPU cycles it takes to convert a pointer/address), especially when you have to do it quite frequently,  for instance (just an example to show the scale of freqency, I know there are better ways for this particular cases):

```
unsigned long long *x;
/* fill data to x*/

for (int i = 0; i < 1000*1000*1000; i++)
{

    A[i]=foo((unsigned char*)x+i);

};
```

Comment: Types only exist at compile-time. That said, these kinds of pointer conversions are often not a good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> (e.g. how many CPU cycles it takes to convert a pointer/address)

In most machine code languages there is only 1 "type" of pointer and so it doesn't cost anything to convert between them. Keep in mind that C++ types really only exist at compile time.

The real issue is that this sort of code can break strict aliasing rules. You can read more about this elsewhere, but essentially the compiler will either produce incorrect code through undefined behavior, or be forced to make conservative assumptions and thus produce slower code. (note that the `char*` and friends is somewhat exempt from the undefined behavior part)

> Optimizers often have to make conservative assumptions about variables in the presence of pointers. For example, a constant propagation process that knows the value of variable x is 5 would not be able to keep using this information after an assignment to another variable (for example, *y = 10) because it could be that *y is an alias of x. This could be the case after an assignment like y = &x.
>
> As an effect of the assignment to *y, the value of x would be changed as well, so propagating the information that x is 5 to the statements following *y = 10 would be potentially wrong (if *y is indeed an alias of x). However, if we have information about pointers, the constant propagation process could make a query like: can x be an alias of *y? Then, if the answer is no, x = 5 can be propagated safely.
>   Another optimization impacted by aliasing is code reordering. If the compiler decides that x is not aliased by *y, then code that uses or changes the value of x can be moved before the assignment *y = 10, if this would improve scheduling or enable more loop optimizations to be carried out.
>
> To enable such optimizations in a predictable manner, the ISO standard for the C programming language (including its newer C99 edition, see section 6.5, paragraph 7) specifies that it is illegal (with some exceptions) for pointers of different types to reference the same memory location. This rule, known as "strict aliasing", sometime allows for impressive increases in performance,[1] but has been known to break some otherwise valid code. Several software projects intentionally violate this portion of the C99 standard. For example, Python 2.x did so to implement reference counting,[2] and required changes to the basic object structs in Python 3 to enable this optimisation. The Linux kernel does this because strict aliasing causes problems with optimization of inlined code.[3] In such cases, when compiled with gcc, the option -fno-strict-aliasing is invoked to prevent unwanted optimizations that could yield unexpected code.
>   [edit]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)#Conflicts_with_optimization

[What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: This code doesn't break the strict aliasing rule because `unsigned char*` is a specific exception (one of the very few).

Comment: But, IIRC, `char` types can safely alias any other type. So the OP code is still correct.

Comment: @MSalters Yeah, I just realized that. I suppose they still prevent optimization though.

Comment: Most of the time casting is a no-op.  However, casting up and down a multiple or virtual inheritance class hierarchy in C++ may involve some additions or subtractions to generate a pointer that does indeed point to the correct part of memory.

Answer (score 8):

On any architecture you're likely to encounter, all pointer types have the same representation, and so conversion between different pointer types representing the same address has no run-time cost. This applies to all pointer conversions in C.

In C++, some pointer conversions have a cost and some don't:

- `reinterpret_cast` and `const_cast` (or an equivalent C-style cast, such as the one in the question) and conversion to or from `void*` will simply reinterpret the pointer value, with no cost.
- Conversion between pointer-to-base-class and pointer-to-derived class (either implicitly, or with `static_cast` or an equivalent C-style cast) may require adding a fixed offset to the pointer value if there are multiple base classes.
- `dynamic_cast` will do a non-trivial amount of work to look up the pointer value based on the dynamic type of the object pointed to.

Historically, some architectures (e.g. PDP-10) had different representations for pointer-to-byte and pointer-to-word; there may be some runtime cost for conversions there.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned long long *x;
/* fill data to x*/

for (int i = 0; i < 1000*1000*1000; i++)
{

    A[i]=foo((unsigned char*)x+i); // bad cast

}
```

Remember, the machine only knows memory addresses, data and code. Everything else (such as types etc) are known only to the Compiler(that aid the programmer), and that does all the pointer arithmetic, only the compiler knows the size of each type.. so on and so forth.

At runtime, there are no machine cycles wasted in converting one pointer type to another because the conversion does not happen at runtime. All pointers are treated as of 4 bytes long(on a 32 bit machine) nothing more and nothing less.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your underlying hardware.

On *most* machine architectures, all pointers are byte pointers, and converting between a byte pointer and a byte pointer is a no-op. On *some* architectures, a pointer conversion may under some circumstances require extra manipulation (there are machines that work with word based addresses for instance, and converting a word pointer to a byte pointer or vice versa will require extra manipulation).

Moreover, this is in general an unsafe technique, as the compiler can't perform any sanity checking on what you are doing, and you can end up overwriting data you didn't expect.